# Filter memberof groups of user

Tags: c#, .net, filter, ldap

I have manage to get a list of the users memberof groups. I want to filter the groups so i only get the groups where "Hey" is included. Something like:
GroupHeyYou,
GroupHeyThere,
GroupYouKnow,
GroupWhatThe

and only returns GroupHeyYou and GroupHeyThere

This is my function:

```
public List<string> GetUserGroupMemberShip()
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = default(DirectoryEntry);            //Binding object.
        DirectorySearcher ds = default(DirectorySearcher);      //Search object.
        SearchResult sr = default(SearchResult);
        List<string> groups = new List<string>();

        string logonUserName = Environment.UserName;
        string logonServer = (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("logonserver")).Remove(0, 2);
        string activeDirectoryPath = "LDAP://" + logonServer + "." + System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

        try
        {
            de = new DirectoryEntry(activeDirectoryPath);
            ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(sAMAccountName=" + logonUserName + ")");
            sr = ds.FindOne();
            if (null != sr)
            {
                DirectoryEntry deUser = new DirectoryEntry(sr.Path);
                object obGroups = deUser.Invoke("Groups");
                foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry deGroups = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
                    groups.Add(deGroups.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return groups;
    }
```

how can i use a filter to do that?

Comment: just an aside, but you really ought to clean-up your directoryEntry's & DirectorySearchers when you're done. They both implement IDisposable as they use unmanaged resources.

Comment: This is my first time working with directoryEntry og DirectorySearcher so didn't know that i had too xD but thanks for mention it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var filteredGroup = groups.FindAll(item =>
{
    return item.Contains("Hey");
});
```

Comment: Putting the code at the end of my function and it complains that not all code paths return a value. This may be a stupid and noob question but how do i use your code snippet?

Comment: replace `return groups;` whith `return groups.FindAll(item =>
{
    return item.Contains("Hey");
});`